# Firefox Add-on SDK: Attache a JS code to all the frames of a page

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, inject

I want to inject a javascript code to the main page of a domain and all of its frames. tabs.activeTab.attach and pageMod contentScript just inject the code to the main page and not its child frames. Is there a way to inject and run a JS code recursively in all the frames of a page?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found that pageMod attaches the JS code in all the frames of a page by default. So it is enough to use pageMod and specify your contentScript.